# Javascript ... passing value is not displaying

Tags: javascript

```js
const sayHello = (name)=> {  
   return `Hey There ${name}`
}
console.log(sayHello('Raju'));
```

console is displaying "Hey There ${name}" but I was expected "Hey There Raju". where is the fault.

Comment: Use **``** instead of `''`

Comment: I have tried that but no invain

Comment: There is no reason for it not to work. Is this your complete code or is there something else?

Comment: its complete code

Comment: I created a snippet. Its working fine for me

Comment: as it is I shared including console output. what's the fault of my code

Comment: You need to use backticks around the `\`Hey There ${name}\`` string not `Raju`